# Table form for selection multiple rows and choosing between actions

Tags: django, select, row

I am putting together a Django website, and am in a rut.

The site features a lot of forms for adding and editing data, which is pretty basic, but when it gets to foreign-key relations, I need more options. Say I have a class 'Product' that is sold, and for all products in database, I want to add an object 'maintenance', 'annual fee' or what not.

I could simply make a form with a select-multiple field, where I select the products i want and then another field for inputting parameters for the maintenance object. This works out alright for adding, but what if I want to edit/delete/draw relations/generate report and stuff like that?

What I am thinking is that it would be great, If the products were listed in a scrollable, sortable, filterable table (These things I can easily handle). What this table would then need is to have me able to select the rows (that would be: objects.) I want to act on, and then have multiple submit buttons for various functions.

The submit buttons, I can handle, but I don't know how to make table rows selectable. Some javascript, I gather?

I read somewhere that if each row had a hidden checkbox tied to the object primary-key, then a javascript could handle clicks on the row and select/deselect the hidden checkbox and color the row appropriately.

Alternatively, there is JQuery's 'Selectable', but that seems very abstract to me.

What would be a good way to go about this? Suggestions? Example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, this took a lot of work, so here goes.

When I want to create a form which uses tabledata instead of user input data, I use the following class:

```
class TableRowForm():
    '''
    This form is special, because usually, forms include a range of inputs
    to be filled out by the user. This form however, no inputs are filled in. The
    form is given a queryset of objects and a list of field names, and with those,
    a table is made. Each row in the table represents an object. clicking a row
    will select the object. Multiple submit buttons can be given with various
    functions. What these buttons have in common is that they all operate on the
    selected objects, e.g. selecting three objects and pressing delete will delete
    those three objects. The form is different in that it does not create new objects,
    it manipulates already existing objects.
    '''
    def __init__(self, queryset, fields):
        if not fields:
            raise Exception('A TableRowForm must be supplied both queryset and fields')
        self.queryset = queryset
        self.fields = fields

    def __unicode__(self):
        '''
        Builds the html table rows for the form.
        '''
        if not self.queryset: return '<tr><td>No data...<td></tr>'
        colcount = 0
        res = ""
        res += "<tr>"
        for f in self.fields:
            res += "<th>"+self.queryset[0]._meta.get_field_by_name(f)[0].verbose_name+"</th>"
        res += "</tr>\n"
        for obj in self.queryset:
            res += '<tr onclick="selectRow(this)">'
            res += '<td><input style="display:none;" type="checkbox" name="slct" id="%s" value="%s"/>'%(obj.pk,obj.pk)

            vals = [getattr(obj, x) for x in self.fields]
            colcount = len(vals)
            for x in vals:
                res += '%s</td><td>'%(str(x))
            res = res[:-4]
            res += '</tr>\n'
        res += '<tr><th colspan="%d"><span style="font-size:9pt;"><b>Selctable table:</b> Click a row to select it</span></th></tr>'%(colcount)

        # Add the javascript that implements functionality
        res += '''\
        <script>
        // Allows for selectable tablerows in forms
        function selectRow(row)
        {
            // Check/uncheck the checkbox
            var chk = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
            chk.checked = !chk.checked;

            // Color the row in response to the checkbox's boolean value
            if (chk.checked) {
                row.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
            } else {
                row.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            }
        }
        </script>'''
        return res
```

What this does is that it takes a queryset of data and a list of the desired fields to be shown, and then it builds the table with the provided data, and a hidden checkboxes for each row.

After the table is built, a javascript is appended to help select the checkboxes and color the table rows accordingly.

Creating such a form might go something like this:

```
trform = TableRowForm(queryset=Item.objects.all(),
                                 fields=('serial',
                                         'prod',
                                         'discount',
                                         'price',
                                         'account',
                                         'vat',))
```

When using this form in a template, it should be done like this

```
<form action="{% url bla.bla.bla %}" method="post">
<table>
{{ form|safe }}
</table>
<input type="submit" name="testform" value="Test" />
</form>
```

The filter '|safe' makes sure that the HTML is interpreted instead of just writting as text.

The reason the table tags are not made automatically is that the form may not be the entire table itself, so the form only make rows for a table.

Putting the 'name' attribute on submit buttons in the form is a great way to manage what action to take, if we have more than one submit button. One could imagine an arbitrary amount of actions to take on a table of data.

Finally, handling the form data, when the submit button is hit, can be done as follows:

```
if 'testform' in request.POST:
        # These two lines fetch all the selected objects from the tablerow form
        selections = request.POST.getlist('slct')
        its = Item.objects.filter(pk__in=selections)
```

This example assumes that the object type used on the table-row-form is Item. 'slct' is the name automatically given to checkboxes in the form. One could imagine making this smarter by allowing the form to be created from an instance of request.POST, letting the form extract information from the POST data automatically, but I havn't gotten that far yet ;)

"request.POST.getlist('slct')" basically gets all values named with 'slct' and puts them in a list. After this, you can easily retrieve the objects they represent by querying primary keys.

I hope this is useful to someone other than myself. I am very proud of what I have achieved :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have to create your own form class - and embed the javascript in there. The proper way to do that is to use [form media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/), or simply do it as below:

```
{% for a in some_queryset %}
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="pk" name="pk" value={{ a.pk }} /></td>
      <td>{{ a.name }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}

# later on ...

<input 
    type="submit"
    name="action1"
    value="Do Action 1"
    id="action1_btn" class="btn btn-primary disabled" />
<input
    type="submit"
    name="action2"
    value="Do Action 2"
    id="action2_btn"
    class="btn btn-danger disabled" />

# and other buttons...
```

Finally, this bit of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#pk').click(function() {
  if ($('input[name="pk"]:checked').length > 0)
  {
     // more than one check box is checked
     $("#action1_btn").removeClass('disabled');
     $("#action2_btn").removeClass('disabled');
     // other actions you want to do

  } else {

     // No check boxes are checked
     $("#action1_btn").addClass('disabled');
     $("#action2_btn").addClass('disabled');
  }
});
</script>
```

*This script enables buttons only when rows are checked.*

Finally, django provides [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) that do exactly what you have replicated here.

Comment: What does the javascript do differently here? I'm not awesome at js :P